# Spacemacs change line background color when has comment

Tags: spacemacs, faces, themes, colors

I currently have a strange behave when my code has comment on Spacemacs. Making it bad to read a file with a lot of comments

[image: comments]

Anyone knows how to change this behave? I tried to search about it and I failed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the comment line and enter `M-x customize-face` and changed the `font-lock-comment-face` with the same background used by the default lines.

Comment: Carlos' solution worked for me. The background color in question for the default spacemacs configuration is `#292B2E`

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work in my config

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
 (setq spacemacs-theme-comment-bg nil)
....
)
```

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! Could you add a brief description of what it's supposed to do? Is the default value `t`? Are there other possible values?

Comment: apparently it is set to a lighter color after the default bg is set.   this setting negates the addition of the alternate bg  this the comment text has a different fg color and the same bg as the rest of the buffer.   Ihave found this to only really apply to the spacemacs theme.